# Using Ansible with a proxy on a GCE Windows instance without an External IP

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ansible, google-compute-engine

The goal is to use Ansible's win_chocolatey module on a GCE instance.

Currently, the GCE instance (Windows Server 2012 R2) is manageable with Ansible (i.e it can be pinged via win_ping), however because it does not have an External IP address it does not have direct internet access.

The Instance is being managed by Ansible via the Local Administrator account, which has had a password reset via the Google SDK (i.e `gcloud compute reset-windows-password`).

I have attempted configuring the Instance to access the internet via a Squid3 proxy (which I have confirmed works), however neither netsh or regex.exe commands work. I have tried running the following using Ansible's win_shell module:

- `set-itemproperty -path 'HKCU:Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' -name ProxyServer -value 'https://gateway-instance.c.project-name.internal:3128'`
- `set-itemproperty -path 'HKCU:Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' -name ProxyEnable -value '1'`
- `reg.exe add "HKCU\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v proxyenable /t reg_DWORD /d 1 /f`
- `reg.exe add "HKCU\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v proxyserver /t reg_SZ /d gateway-instance.c.project-name.internal:3128 /f"`
- `netsh winhttp set proxy proxy-server="http://gateway-instance.c.project-name.internal:3128"`

I've noticed that the commands to change the registry do nothing until the Administrator has logged in (i.e via RDP); I assume because the account then has a profile to change the registry for.

On Linux Instances I've been able to set the Environment variables, however [the Ansible documentation](http://(https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_environment.html).) states that *environment: is not currently supported for Windows targets*.

What can be done on the GCE Instance, or elsewhere, so that Ansible modules can access the internet?

Comment: Not sure if that helps, I'm also pretty sure that you tried but there is an [win_environment](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/win_environment_module.html) module.

Comment: In Ansible when you set the environment for a task/play for a Linux machine you are essentially setting local environment variables (like you would through `export`).


The win_environment module sets Windows environment variables (which as far as I know won't effect Powershell/Ansible?)

Comment: You are right with that. The documentation states that the change is not broadcasted. So I would try to setup a `reboot handler` for the `win_environment` task.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? If so, please consider posting an answer, as this will benefit the community.

Comment: @Marilu The short answer is no. The workaround I ended up implementing was to deploy a linux webserver, which then uses Ansible's `environment` flag to route through the Squid3 proxy as required to download files that are needed by Windows instances. For example the webserver hosts the Ansible ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1 script which instances then grab and run on startup (i.e `iex (new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('http://{{ webserverIP }}/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1')`.